# recalculating values based on number of days and show them on text fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, momentjs

I have a php page.

There are two date fields on my page and 10 input fields showing various charges.

On selecting check-in and check-out date and clicking submit button, it calculates number of days. Im using moment js for that.

Once number of days are calculated, I want value of all text fields like rent and others to be multiplied by number of days and show the value in respective fields. This is my php page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
From: <input id="fromDate" type='date' />
To: <input id="toDate" type='date' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="btn">Submit</button><hr />
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
$("#btn").on('click', function(e) {
    var fromDate = $('#fromDate').val(), 

    toDate = $('#toDate').val(), 
    from, to, duration;

    from = moment(fromDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'); 
    to = moment(toDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'); 

   /* using diff */
   duration = to.diff(from, 'days')

   /* show the result */
   $('#result').text(duration + ' days');
});

</script>
```

Here is one of the fields whose value I want to be updated

```
<div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="control-label col-sm-4"><b>Room Rent :</b></div>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
            
              <input text="text" name="ipt_item_1" id="ipt_item_1" 
              value="1500">
              <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" name="chk_item_1" 
              class="chk-amount" data-target="ipt_item_1"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

I don't know how to do it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How is this a mysql question?

Comment: And how is it a PHP question? Sounds like it should probably be tagged with JavaScript and momentJS. But it's unclear due to lack of detail. We're not going to be able to give you a proper answer unless you show us what code you've got already

Comment: Thanks for the update. So...where's the problem? Get the value of each field you want, multiply it by your days value, and write the new value back into the field. Judging by your existing code you already know how to get and set the values of fields and elements. It's unclear where exactly you're stuck or what you've tried

Comment: Do I have to write another function? There are 10 fields on my page and Im not finding any clue on how should I do it.

Comment: Do you want the calculation to happen at the same time as you calculate the number of days, or at a different time?

Comment: Preferably at the same time.There is another reason which is making me clueless, that is , on my page, I have a function called on keyup and keydown of these 10 input fields, which updates the values of another 3 variables. I don't want this functionality to be disturbed.

Comment: So for the calculation, it makes sense to put it into the same function, so that you've already got the days value available. After that, just do what I outlined above to get and set the values. Is there a specific issue with that?

Comment: What do you mean by "not disturbed"? You mean you want that same function (as would be triggered by keyup/keydown) to also be triggered when the values are changed by your code? That would seem logical. Or are you saying it should not be triggered? Your statement is ambiguous. Try to always be precise about what you want.

Comment: Yes I mean the same function to also be triggered when the values are changed by the code I'll write for multiplying values with number of days. Hope I'm clear now.

Comment: Yes that part is clear. Are you happy with how to do the multiplying now? If you have written the code shown in your question, then doing the next part will involve some of the same techniques and jQuery calls.